# How to display frames per second in an Java Applet in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, frame-rate

This is a simple bouncing ball
and i would to be able to display the the FPS while the program is running

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class BallApplet extends Applet implements Runnable {
   private int ballX, ballY;
   private final int radius = 50;

   public void start1() {
      Thread th = new Thread(this);
      th.start();
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      int dx = 2;
      int dy = 2;
      int speed = 2;
      // This will reduce the load the applet has on the runtime
      // system..

      Thread.currentThread().setPriority(…
      while (true) {
         ballX += dx;
         ballY += dy;
         repaint();
         if (ballX + radius > getWidth())
            dx = -speed;
         else if (ballX < 0)
            dx = speed;
         if (ballY + radius > getHeight())
            dy = -speed;
         else if (ballY < 0)
            dy = speed;
         try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
         } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
         }
      }
   }

   // set up BallApplet object
   public void init() {
      ballX = 0;
      ballY = getHeight() / 2;
   }

   // Drawing instructions…
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.fillOval(ballX - radius, ballY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
   }

   // The standard Applet “GO” function…
   public void start() {
      Thread th = new Thread(this);
      th.start();
   }
}
```

Thanks Lochy

Comment: Please format your code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
long nextSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
int frameInLastSecond = 0;
int framesInCurrentSecond = 0;


public void paint() {
    // ... other drawing code goes here

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentTime > nextSecond) {
        nextSecond += 1000;
        frameInLastSecond = framesInCurrentSecond;
        framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
    }
    framesInCurrentSecond++;

    g.drawString(framesInLastSecond + " fps", 20, 20);
}
```

BTW, your code is not thread-safe: as `paint()` is invoked from the Event Dispatch Thread, and `run()` in a thread you started, the methods should synchronize access to shared state (the fields of `BallApplet`).

Also note that `paint()` will be invoked if a part of the window that was previously occluded by another window must be repainted. The above code will count that as a "frame". If you don't want that, you shouldn't trigger drawing using `repaint()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have one frame appearing every 20 milliseconds, or 50 frames per second. However, due to the nature of `Thread.sleep()`, it might be shorter or longer than 20 milliseconds in between each frame.

If you want to display 50 fps, look into [`JLabel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html).

/e1
Why do you have two methods (`start()` and `start1()`) which do exactly the same thing?